# how to subtract images from each other in php

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I have a series of PNG files that exhibit subtle differences over time. Is there a way, using PHP, to take pairs of PNGs and create a third file representing the difference between them?

I guess that it may be possible to do something similar with [Slicer](http://www.slicer.org/), but (1) that may be a bit of an overkill for my needs, and (2) I was looking for something native to PHP.

Comment: What exactly is the result you are looking for? How do you want to visualize the changes?

Comment: I haven't yet thought it out in much detail. Roughly, I thought of "heat-mapping" the differences, blue for similar hue/brightness, red for strongly differing ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try Imagick's `compareImageChannels()`: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimagechannels.php

Note that PHP itself has no native image manipulation functions. Anything to do with images in PHP is provided with plugins to external libraries.